# Next line code runs before Promise actually resolves

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refactor an old piece of code which is all nested as one large function. In there main function there are several http calls that return data and one call that reads from the local storage.

The first thing that I tried to refavtor out was reading from the localstorage as that caused some problems. I created a separate function with a promise that read from the localstorage and when it's done will return the value (at leats that was my purpose). The only problem is that my application doesn't wait for the promise to resolve.

My huge monolithic faction that I am refactoring:

```
 function activate() {
    HasAdminRole();
    getStates();


    datacontext.graph.getAboutMeBasic().then(function (dataUserDetails) {

        // If the user isn't a guest get the shared and personal routes.
        if (dataUserDetails.userType !== 'Guest') {
            vm.isUserGuest = false;
            getNavRoutesFromDb();
            getPersnonalDashboardSetting();
            getPersonalRoutesFromDb();
        }
        // If the user is a guest we only want to load the shared dashboards.
        else {

            vm.isUserGuest = true;

            // get all the groups a user is member of.
            datacontext.graph.getUserGroups().then(function (userGroups) {

                // get chosen navigation by the userSetting value.
                datacontext.usersetting.getUserSettingsByKey('Navigation').then(function (chosenNavigationName) {


                    console.log('de gekozen nav', chosenNavigationName)
                    // When a user is created the defautl navigation is "Algemeen", an external
                    // user is never allowed to see this navigation, thus it's save to say 
                    // that a user will be navigated to the external navigation
                    if (chosenNavigationName === 'Algemeen') {
                        chosenNavigationName = 'Klantenportaal';

                        console.log('before promise');


                        getUserData().then(function(userData) {
                            console.log('the user info', userData)

                            console.log('after promise');

                            console.log('the user: ', userInfo)

                            datacontext.settings.getSettingByName("Navigation").then(function(navigationId) {
                                console.log('nav id', navigationId);
                                datacontext.usersetting.updateUserSetting(userInfo.oneUserId, 11, 'Klantenportaal').then(function (userSettings) {
                                    console.log('user setting from update', userSettings)
                                });
                            })
                        })

                    }
                    console.log('nieuwe nav naam', chosenNavigationName);

                    try {
                        // get the allowedGroupId for the chosen navigation value.
                        datacontext.navigation.getNavigationByName(chosenNavigationName).then(function (result) {

                            // if the API returns error we redirect the user back to not authorized page.
                            if (result === 'error') {
                                window.location.href = '/Error/notauthorized';
                            }

                            var allowedGroupId = result.allowedGroupId;

                            if (allowedGroupId !== '') {
                                var isUserInGroup = 0;

                                // Loop over the groups a member is in. 
                                userGroups.map(function (group) {
                                    if (group.id === allowedGroupId) {
                                        isUserInGroup = 1
                                    }
                                });

                                //  If none of the groups match the allowedGroup, Log out the user.
                                if (isUserInGroup === 0) {

                                    window.location.href = '/Error/notauthorized';
                                }

                                // if the external group has no allowed group Id we log the user out. 
                                // We do this to prevent that all external users on a tenant can visit the customer portal.
                            } else {
                                window.location.href = '/Error/notauthorized';
                            }
                        })
                    } catch (e) {
                        window.location.href = '/Error/notauthorized';
                    }


                });
            });



            getPersnonalDashboardSetting();
            getExternalUserNavRoutes();
        }
    });

}
```

My separate promise function to read from the localstorage

```
function getUserData() {
        console.log('reading promise');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           var  userInfo = textservice.getUserInfoFromLocalStorage();
            resolve(userInfo);
        });
    }
```

[image]

If we look in the console, we can see that the the promise isn't resolved yet but the code continues. I appreciate if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `getUserInfoFromLocalStorage` do?

Comment: I think you'll have a better comprehension of your issue after reading some topics about the asynchronous behavior of javascript. You could start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code doesn't wait just because you called a Function that returns a `Promise`.

You also  need to *chain* your Promises.

Code that needs to run after a `Promise` has resolved needs to be put in the next `then()` of the Promise chain.

Look at this example:

```js
const getAsyncValue = (value) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(value)
    }, 300)
  })
}

getAsyncValue(1)
  .then(value => {
    // getAsyncValue(1) Promise has resolved,
    // value = 1
    return getAsyncValue(2)
  })
  .then(value => {
    // getAsyncValue(1) Promise has resolved,
    // value = 2

    // oops, forgot to return the following Promise.
    getAsyncValue(3)
    
    // getAsyncValue(3) Promise has NOT resolved yet.
  })
  .then(value => {
    // getAsyncValue(3) Promise is still NOT resolved,
    // value = undefined
    console.log('end')
    
    // At some point in the future, getAsyncValue(3) resolves, 
    // but it's too late.
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is `await` the promise. Looking into your big chunk of code, when calling the function `getUserData()`, change this to:

```
await getUserData()
```

It will then wait for the `getUserData()` method to finish executing (promise to resolve) before moving onto the next line of code.

Comment: I'd say most of the code needs to be reworked to either use chained Promises, or `async/await` but not both, at least in that huge chunk.

Comment: I'd recommend using `async/await` syntax as chaining promises can become very untidy.

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure but if you want to next code you need await can you put on the front await getUserData().then...
May be it will work